# If while sending a file with "readfile" I modify the file, will the download fail?

Tags: php, apache, http, memory, file-io

If I send a big (200mb) file to the browser with `readfile()`, and while the user is downloading I modify the file, will the download finish succesfully? If not - how do I modify large files that are constantly being downloaded?

Comment: Depends on where/when you make the modification - overwriting some bytes near the start of the file AFTER the user's already gotten the bytes won't affect the download. Changing bytes before+after the current download spot will result in a corrupted file. Add some bytes at the end may not show up if the browser strictly honors the original Content-length header it received.

Answer (score 2):

No, it will not finish successfully if you edit the file data directly. A corrupted file would be received.

However...

In Linux, if you `rm` or `mv` a file, any program that already has that file open will continue to access it. It is only once the file is closed that the file is completely released. Therefore, you could safely edit your large file with these steps:

1. Copy the file away to a temporary name.
2. Edit the file.
3. `rm file_being_downloaded; mv new_file file_being_downloaded;`

I have not tested this, but that should allow all people downloading the 200mb file to receive their copy completely in tact, and new downloaders will get your updated version.

Comment: Does php's 'unlink()' use 'rm' internally?

Comment: Linux filesystems actually "unlink" a file. To be accurate, PHP's `unlink()` is actually calling the `unlink()` system call, as does `rm`.

Comment: I become curious if PHP's `readfile()` actually keeps the file open throughout the entire read, so I looked at the PHP source. It does. The C code effectively looks like this PHP equivalent:

`$fp = fopen();
if ($fp) {
    fpassthru($fp);
    fclose($fp);
}` (PHP v5.3.6, source ext/standard/file.c, Lines 1484-1489). I am still very interested if this works as you intend. Please report back if you test it.

Comment: I cannot test this right now but i'll try to do it in a couple of days

Comment: Just to follow up, did this work? I never tested it either, but I'm curious to know for an upcoming file manager project.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test this but most probably the download will get corrupted and `readfile()` will return false and throw an error. Another option, *iff* `readfile()` *locks* the file is that you won't be able to write to the file until it has finished reading it - I don't think this is the case though.

If I were you I would duplicate the file, serve it and then delete it. You might also want to load the file contents into memory and serve that, but for a 200MB file this would be unpractical...

```
$file = '/path/to/file.200mb';
$temp = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), time() . '_');

copy($file, $temp);    
readfile($temp);    
unlink($temp);
```

Comment: @barin: Updated my answer with two possible solutions.

Comment: i don't quite understand what you mean by "duplicate the file, serve it and then delete it" - could you please elaborate a little?

Comment: @barin: I mean copy the file, check my update for some sample code.

Comment: nice solution. But is it really practical to duplicate a file for each download?

Comment: @barin: That would depend on your specific usage, but I think so. In the end you'll have to always duplicate the file, either to disk or memory... @jimp solution seems a bit better but I have some doubts it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends on how the download is being handled.

If the file is saved to a separate memory position on the server, and you modify the actual file. Seeing as the user is trying to download the file in the alternate memory position, it shouldnt affect it.

Comment: `readfile()` flushes the output directly, it doesn't load the whole file into memory.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to put up a new file, and then update the code to load the new file. That way users who are downloading the old file will continue to do so, but you will be able to transition to a new file.